# I cant get my clear fix to work

Tags: html, css

[image]I can get my clear fix to work, I've tried multiple different clearfixes and none of them seem to work. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?
Also I've noticed some examples using a single `:` instead of two before after. Is that a typo I'm seeing? It doesn't seem correct, but I've seen it written [image: that way multiple times.]
https://jsfiddle.net/acfs9293/

```
 .clearfix::after{
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further what are you trying to accomplish in your fiddle? What is wrong in it?

Comment: Your code is working as expected (`clearfix` has height of floated child elements). `:` and `::` is not typo but old and new notation for pseudo-elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: My header is collapsing a bit when I float its children, so I'm using a clearfix to clear the floats but the clearfix isn't work.

Comment: @Brandon Please provide screenshot of what you see and what you want to get. Provide browser information too (IE5, Chrome, FF, other; Windows, Mac, Linux)

Comment: I don't understand the page looks the same whether I apply the clearfix or leave it without it

Comment: I'm using chrome, I'm not sure how to attach a screen shot in the comments.  I noticed the header didnt collapse, like I thought. It just got smaller when I float its children,because they moved, but thats odd, i thought the parents of floated children are supposed to collapse. whether I deleted the                                                              .clearfix::after{
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;}                                                                                           or leave it, the page stays exactly the same.

Comment: You can edit your question and add a screenshot there

Comment: ok, they both look the same with or without the clearfix, which is odd because the header's children are floated

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out final, I had my header set to a fixed position, I didnt realize fixed positioned elements dont collapse

Answer (score 0):

please use only ':' for Pseudo classes.

```
.clearfix:after{
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

Example for Pseudo element.

```
h1::first-line {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. `after` is a pseudo element.

Comment: `::` is recommended in css3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after